# Where to apply CSS transitions?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Should I apply `transition` properties to an `element` or to the `element:pseudo-class`?

What is preferable,

```
p {
  color: blue;
  transition: 2s 22ms
}

p:hover {
  color: red
}
```

or

```
p {
  color: blue
}

p:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: 2s 22ms
}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.

1st option :

> Your text in blue -> mouseover -> **transition effect** -> your text in
>   red -> mouseout -> **transition effect** -> your text in blue

2nd option :

> Your text in blue -> mouseover -> **transition effect** -> your text in
>   red -> mouseout -> your text in blue

Choose according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the transition to be different depending on the pseudo class you must use the second option. But if you don't care, use the first one.

```
input {
  color: blue
}

input:hover {
  color: red;
  transition: 2s 22ms
}

input:focus {
  color: red;
  transition: 3s
}

input:active {
  color: red;
  transition: 4s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply your transition to `:hover`, the transition will only happen on `mouseover` and not on `mouseout`. Applying the transition to the element rather than its `:hover` will make the transition happen on both `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

Here's a [fiddle to help illustrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpgzz/).

Comment: What are mouseout and mouseout?

Comment: They are events. Here's a breakdown: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter && https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseout